# Перенос готового сайта на Битрикс

Tags: 1с, веб-программирование, битрикс

Есть готовый сайт с версткой в html, css, js. Но он без CMS и нужно перенести его на битрикс, искал в гугле - ответа не нашёл.

При создании сайта, битрикс даёт мне стандартные шаблоны, которые мне, по сути не нужны, это первая сторона вопроса, вторая: как мне импортировать html в сам битрикс, знаю, что нужно переносить всё в `header.php` и `footer.php`, но каким образом?

Comment: Как себе представляете перенос статического сайта в CMS?
Можно только данные перенести в базу данных битрикса, которые будут использованы при динамическом формировании контента. оформление тоже придется затачивать под битрикс. в общем копи-паст тут не прокатит.

Comment: 1 как вариант можно спарсить весь контент с вашего сайта 
2 загнать его в формат, который поддерживает битрикс для импорта
3 выполнить импорт контента из это файла на сайт на битриксе

написание парсер - это уже фриланс

Comment: @NMD по сути надо дизайн просто перенести, вот задача основная.

Comment: content замените на workarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот этот [раздел учебных курсов](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=04564&LESSON_PATH=3913.4564) Вам поможет. Посмотрите также как сделаны стандартные шаблоны. С header и footer все достаточно просто, сложнее будет с шаблонами компонентов, если вы раньше никогда не сталкивались с битриксом. Необходимы хотя бы начальные знания php. А еще - крайне рекомендую почитать [вот этот пост](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/community/blogs/howto/to-start-from.php).

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример как делают интеграцию верстки https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHqcvWfyEh8 . Но на самом деле - учебные курсы вам выше ссылку дали помогают во всех вопросах связанных с битрикс.